# How did I get extra space on my Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

To my knowledge a free Google account gets 15 GB of storage by default. Somehow I now have 115 GB. How did this happen and how long do I have it for? I know smartphone sometimes prompts me to take pictures of an area I am in. Is this the result of some sort of rewards program?

Comment: Did you get a Google Pixel or Chromebook? That'll result in some extra GDrive storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Google is promoting the Local Guides feature on its Maps application:

> #### Google Drive storage promotion
>
> Local Guides who reach Level 4 by 11 p.m. EST on 17 March 2017 can unlock 100 GB of free Google Drive storage. The benefit must be redeemed within 30 days of issue and is **valid for one year**. This promotion will expire after the cut-off date.
>   <sub>Source:https://support.google.com/local-guides/answer/6345112?hl=en-GB</sub>

Apparently, you sent enough pictures and shared enough knowledge with the Maps network to qualify for the reward.

Comment: Any idea how I can know which day the 1 year finishes on?

Comment: @northerner It should probably another question (as I don't know the answer), but you can see your storage settings on this link: https://www.google.com/settings/storage (must be logged in, content might not appear in your native language)

Comment: They should send an email warning you ahead of time.  I believe mine came about a month prior to the end of the term for a Chromebook purchase promotion.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to https://www.google.com/settings/storage and click "view details" under the pie chart, it'll show you exactly where your storage allotment is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

If you recently bought a new phone/device chances are the manufacturer has a deal with Google, and that could be how you got it...